# Adding multiple XML attributes to a pytest xml in conftest.py

Tags: xml, pytest, conftest

I have multiple pytest scripts that run independently, I want to build a mechanism to add xml attributes to the tests in the script to run in the conftest.py script on collection.
So far i've found online a call :

```
request.config._xml.node_reporter(item.nodeid).add_attribute('spam', 'eggs')
```

that can be run in the  `pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook .
but when i try to run this i get:

```
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

Error
Any idea what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dug some more in the documentation and found that if you add this to the conftest.py:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def record_index(record_xml_attribute):
    record_xml_attribute('index', '15')
```

it does exactly what i need